# What did echo and quotes do?

Tags: bash

```
nkcoder@nkcoder:bash$ ls
doublebracket.sh  for.sh  if.sh  quote.sh  singlebracket.sh  test.sh
nkcoder@nkcoder:bash$ ls | wc -l
6
nkcoder@nkcoder:bash$ echo $(ls)
doublebracket.sh for.sh if.sh quote.sh singlebracket.sh test.sh
nkcoder@nkcoder:bash$ echo $(ls) | wc -l
1
nkcoder@nkcoder:bash$ echo "$(ls)"
doublebracket.sh
for.sh
if.sh
quote.sh
singlebracket.sh
test.sh
nkcoder@nkcoder:bash$ echo "$(ls)" | wc -l
6
```

1. The output of `ls` is 6 lines, where is the newline ?
2. why quotes affects the result when using "$(ls)" ?

I'm really confused, could anybody help to provide some explanation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See http://stuff.lhunath.com/parser.png for a high-level overview of how bash's command processing works, or http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser for a more detailed overview. Note in particular, in step 6, how _escaped_ spaces are not used for word-splitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read it, there are multiple questions here:

---

#### Why does `ls | wc -l` report a different number of lines of output than that seen running `ls` manually?

`ls` checks whether its stdout is a TTY -- the same check your own scripts can do with `[[ -t 1 ]]`. If that test returns true, it modifies its output to be one line per file by default.

---

#### Why does `echo $(ls)` differ from `echo "$(ls)"`?

The output from expansions -- such as `$(ls)` or `$foo` is *word-split* if the expansion was not quoted.

Word-splitting happens on characters in the shell variable `IFS`, or -- by default -- the space character, the tab, and the newline.

Results from that splitting are then substituted as individual arguments to the command being run. So:

```
$ rm -rf tmp.d && mkdir -p tmp.d && cd tmp.d && touch "hello cruel" world
$ echo $(ls)
```

...will first run `ls`. Because output is not to a TTY, the output from `ls` looks like this:

```
hello cruel
world
```

However, because the expansion was not inside quotes, the shell then splits that block into words. Because both the newline and the space character are in IFS by default, the fact that `hello cruel` is a single filename is lost. Thus, we run:

```
$ echo "hello" "cruel" "world"
```

By contrast, if you run:

```
$ echo "$(ls)"
```

...then the shell doesn't string-split on whitespace, so it invokes:

```
$ echo 'hello cruel
world'
```

Mind you, if you really want to iterate over files, you shouldn't be using `ls` at all. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: +1. [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) had a similar/complete answer to this question (with +4). But, I guess it disappeared into the SO ether.

Comment: @BroSlow, I'm a bit ashamed to have potentially been part of the cause of that -- on reading that answer, I entirely missed its discussion of string-splitting (which was a few sentences with no examples, emphasis, or other formatting), and left a comment leveraging criticism on the basis of that perceived omission. (In my defense, I wasn't the only person to misread it that way -- piojo similarly read that answer to be focusing on the isatty() case and omitting the differences in word-splitting behavior).

Comment: (addendum: not a few sentences, but a single sentence alone).

Answer (score 2):

In bash, all unquoted arguments (including an argument generated by command substitution (`` or $())) is combined into a single line. Using quotes keeps the argument (the command substitution output) in its original form, so the newlines are preserved.

To see the difference, you can run:

```
function three_lines()
{
    echo one; echo two; echo three
}
$ three_lines
one
two
three
$ echo `three_lines`
one two three
$ echo "`three_lines`"
one
two
three
```

Comment: Not sure if this is wrong or misleading, but `man bash`, and read the `Word Splitting` section.

Comment: Yeah, I just edited it to clarify. It's not the command substitution that combines the lines, it's bash's argument parsing.

Comment: I agree that this answer correctly describes the problem and its solution -- the only thing that prevents a full endorsement is somewhat sloppy use of language. (It's not "argument parsing" that's at issue, but post-expansion string splitting).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's also `split into a sequence of words on $IFS` rather than `combined into a single line` (which would be accurate if IFS was set to `$'\n'`). But more importantly it doesn't answer the full question of why `ls` behaves differently when stdout is piped. Not sure why `Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams` deleted his more complete answer.

Comment: @BroSlow, as I read it, the focus of the question is on why `echo $(ls)` differs from `echo "$(ls)"`, as opposed to why both of those differ from `ls` -- which is the only portion of the question that answer covered effectively and thoroughly (the rest of the answer used jargon someone asking this question wouldn't necessarily know, and didn't give examples). Though you make a point -- a completely thorough answer would cover all three.

Comment: Because this answer still hasn't been amended to address given concerns, I've added my own.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes will preserve the spaces and new lines of `ls` command to `echo` command and that is the reason when you are using double quotes you are getting actual count rather than using with out quotes.

```
# echo hai\
> bye
haibye
# echo "hai
> bye"
hai
bye
```